# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi aplicación no pida permisos para Escribir en el dispositivo?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-manifest

Esta es la imagen que estoy Tratando de compartir

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Drawable mDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();

        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Design", null);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Holaaaaa");

        share.setType("text/plain");

        share.setType("image/*");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);


        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartir"));

    }
});
```

Comment: No puedes, las medidas de seguridad impuestas por Android están ahí precisamente para dar seguridad. Todas las aplicaciones de Android necesitan que el usuario acepte cada uno de los permisos necesarios para que funcione la app. Si el usuario niega un permiso, no puedes hacer nada excepto insistir en que lo acepte y/o salirte de la app para que no pueda usarla sin ese permiso.

Comment: Cómo hago para que pida el permiso, , porque si te fijas en mi codigo no tengo ese metodo para que pida permiso.

Comment: Necesitas declarar en el manifest el permiso de lectura y escritura.  El de escritura hasta la versión máxima 28, a partir de ahí se usa la de read.  Y para declarar permisos, el blog oficial de Android lo explica https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419